# GPS crashing activity

Tags: android, gps, location

I am trying another whole new attempt at retrieving my lat and lng from gps in android. With the new code, it first opened my activity succesfully but I did not get any gps coordinates. I then unplugged my phone and moved it toward a window and it eventually crashed. I then decided to try this again but with it actually plugged in, in order to get the error report when it crashed by the window.

The second time I started the app, I can now no longer get into the activity without it crashing with this error:

```
12-10 11:53:52.923      398-398/com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro/com.example.beerportfoliopro.FindBrewery}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2517)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.beerportfoliopro.FindBrewery.onLocationChanged(FindBrewery.java:67)
            at com.example.beerportfoliopro.FindBrewery.onCreate(FindBrewery.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5195)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2473)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2574)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:162)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1413)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5789)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:843)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-10 11:53:52.933  24060-24091/system_process E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Process: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro
12-10 11:53:52.933  24060-24091/system_process E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ App crashed! Package: com.beerportfolio.beerportfoliopro v22 (3.0)
12-10 11:53:52.933  24060-24091/system_process E/EmbeddedLogger﹕ Application Label: BeerPortfolio Pro
```

The code for my activity is:

```
public class FindBrewery extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.beer_location_list);
        //latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        //longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Location Not available " + provider,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));

        Toast.makeText(this, "Attempting async task" + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //call asycn task for location
        String url = "myURL";

        Log.d("urlTest", url);

        //async task goes here
        new GetNearbyBreweries(this).execute(url);



    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

What I am trying to accomplish is, when the activity is started it retrieves the users location, then sends the lng and lat to my async task which then retrieves a list of locations from my database and populates a list.

Comment: forget to initialize `latituteField` and `longitudeField` TextViews before calling `setText` method

Comment: why are you calling `onLocationChanged` manually? that is a big no no

Comment: onLocationChanged is a callback. As previous comment states,you mustn't call it directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
     Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    // Initialize the location fields
    if (location != null) {
        System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
        onLocationChanged(location);
```

You call `onLocationChanged` programmatically.  This is wrong.  What you really want is `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates`.  See here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener)

Your location is NULL because you are telling your app that you have a location, when in fact you do not.  That results in the NullPointerException when you do this:

```
    int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
    int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
    latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
    longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
```

If you wait for the location update to fire, then it will work correctly.

Comment: The real problem is with the two unintialized TextViews latituteField and longitudeField... The location is not null, since he actually checks for null Location after locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

Comment: @luciofm that is also an issue.  I don't see `latituteField` and `longitudeField` being initialized anywhere in his sample code.  Even if they were though, he never actually asked the LocationManager to get a location.

Comment: he asked for the last known location locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

Comment: Yes, but that value can be null.  The correct behavior is to have the location manager retrieve the current location, and it will call onLocationChanged()

Comment: I cannot see how that value could be null... right after locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider); he checks if location != null before calling onLocationChanged

Answer (score 0):

Or might you have not added permission needed for getting gps location, and it might be giving you NullPointerException as it is empty.